# I'm getting comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
static NSInteger *previousPage = 0;

    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;

    float fractionalPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x/pageWidth;

    NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
    if(previousPage != page){ //page has changed

        previousPage = page;
    }
```

I'm getting the error for the previousPage != page condition

Also, the previousPage = page is giving me "incompatible integer to pointer conversion..."

Comment: why is previousPage a pointer?

Comment: Why do you create an NSInteger pointer instead of just an NSInteger variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the declaration

```
static NSInteger *previousPage = 0;
```

in your code, which declares `previousPage` to be a pointer to an integer (not an integer), and initializes it to the `null` pointer (not the value `0` zero).

In

```
if(previousPage != page){ //page has changed

    previousPage = page;
}
```

you compare the pointer value of `previousPage` to the integer value of `page`, hence the error. Simple drop the `*` in the declaration of `previousPage`.

```
static NSInteger previousPage = 0;
```